# After selecting image from image picker , flutter app crashes

Tags: flutter, dart

It works good when I tab on selecting image from camera. After selecting image from camera it suddenly crashes and goes back to previous screen .. terminal is show no error .. m using try & catch method but it catch no error as well.

```
Future pickimage() async {
   
   try{
  await ImagePicker.pickImage(
      source: ImageSource.camera,
      imageQuality: 50,
    ).then((img) => setState(() {
          immage = img;
          imagefile = File(immage.path);
        }));

    if (imagefile != null) {
      print('heloo data is saving to database');
      await saveimage();
    }
   }catch(e){
   print(e);
   } 
  }

   m using latest image_picker() version this is my pub dependences 

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0
  carousel_slider: ^2.3.1
  animated_text_kit: ^1.3.1
  cloud_firestore: ^0.14.3
  progress_dialog: ^1.2.4
  firebase_auth: ^0.18.4+1
  firebase_core: ^0.5.3
  google_maps_flutter: ^1.0.6
  geolocator: ^6.1.5
  geoflutterfire: ^2.2.1
  image_picker: ^0.6.7+22
  firebase_storage: ^5.2.0
  latlng: ^0.0.2
  location: ^3.1.0
  simple_animations: ^2.4.0
  liquid_swipe: ^1.5.0
  otp_text_field: ^1.0.1
  charts_flutter: ^0.9.0
  flutter_echarts: ^1.5.0
  flutter_staggered_animations: "^0.1.2"
```

Answer (score 4):

Have you added few lines of configuration on AndroidManifest.xml ?

You should add:

```
<activity
  android:name="com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity"
  android:screenOrientation="portrait"
  android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"/>
```

check this url: https://pub.dev/packages/image_cropper/versions/1.3.1
and section: How to install

Answer (score 0):

This is an error in the plugin. You can track the similar issues on [GitHub](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues?q=is%3Aopen+label%3A%22p%3A+image_picker) (for example [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/66322) and [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/63067)) and provide your error and device hardware info for developers.

Comment: i dont find any solution for my purpose

Comment: Some issues may be in resolving phase, it's meaning that on some devices library can crashed and not solution available at this moment.

Answer (score 0):

Any Feedback on this?

It seems it happening every time i call pickImage.

Future getImage() async {
final _imageFiles =
await ImagePicker().getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

```
if (_imageFiles != null) {
  File _imageFile = await Navigator.of(context).push(
    MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (_) => ImageCropper(file: File(_imageFiles.path))),
  );
  if (_imageFile != null) {
    setState(() {
      profilePicChange = _imageFile.path;
      // Navigator.pop(context);
    });
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case apps crush with message "Lost connection to device." both on real device and on simulator.

Comment: I found a solution.

on Android Add UCropActivity into your AndroidManifest.xml

<activity
    android:name="com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"/>

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/image_cropper/versions/1.3.1  check section:How to install

Answer (score 0):

final ImagePicker picker = ImagePicker();

final XFile? image = await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

final XFile? photo = await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);

Things to change

ImagePicker picker = ImagePicker();

XFile? image = await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

XFile? photo = await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);

it's only working inside real device because it use your camera app

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).